# Is there a python function to fill missing data with consecutive value

Tags: python

I want to Fill in these missing numbers in column `b` with the consecutive values `1` and `2`.

This is what I have done:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 4, 7,8,4],
'b': [1, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 5]})

df['b'].fillna({'b':[1,2]}, inplace=True)
```

but nothing is done.

Comment: Can you add what's the output you're getting + what is the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with an array:

```
df.loc[df['b'].isnull(), 'b'] = [1, 2]
```

What you're attempting is possible but cumbersome with [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
nulls = df['b'].isnull()
df['b'] = df['b'].fillna(pd.Series([1, 2], index=nulls[nulls].index))
```

You *may* be looking for [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) but the above solutions are generic given an input list or array.

If, on the other hand, you want to fill nulls with a sequence `1, 2, 3, etc`, you can use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
# fillna solution
df['b'] = df['b'].fillna(df['b'].isnull().cumsum())

# loc solution
nulls = df['b'].isnull()
df.loc[nulls, 'b'] = nulls.cumsum()
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to fill only 2 NaNs

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that was possible! It's possible that OP wants to fill the NaNs *with a list* though - ie, `1,[1,2],3)` etc

Answer (score 1):

You can't feed `fillna` a list of values, as stated [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3435) and in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html). Also, if you're selecting the column, no need to tell `fillna` which column to use. You could do:

```
df.fillna({'b':1}, inplace=True)
```

Or

```
df['b'].fillna(1, inplace=True)
```

By the way, `inplace` is on the way to deprecation in Pandas, the preferred way to do this is, for example

```
df = df.fillna({'b':1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can interpolate. Example:

```
s = pd.Series([0, 1, np.nan, 3])
s.interpolate()

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
```

Comment: Is this what OP wanted?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand wording " consecutive values 1 and 2" correctly, the solution may be:

```
from itertools import isclice, cycle

filler = [1, 2]
nans = df.b.isna()
df.loc[nans, 'b'] = list(islice(cycle(filler), sum(nans)))
```